# React Native Network Error when create Release build for android

Tags: android, react-native

I upgraded my React native app 0.57 to 0.59. Everything is working fine with the react-native run-android command. But when I create a Release build for android and hitting any API like login API for login. It is giving following error on logcat.

```
2019-08-22 14:38:13.432 16058-16222/? E/ReactNativeJS: errorTypeError: Network request failed
2019-08-22 14:38:13.444 16058-16224/? E/unknown:ReactNative: console.error: "errorTypeError: Network request failed", stack:
    <unknown>@1002:3830
    f@110:155
    <unknown>@110:882
    y@115:657
    C@115:1021
    callImmediates@115:3216
    callImmediates@-1
    value@28:2873
    <unknown>@28:1264
    value@28:2565
    value@28:1234
    value@-1
    value@-1
2019-08-22 14:38:37.717 1049-1220/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-08-22 14:38:43.513 2286-2469/? E/SyncManager: Bind attempt failed - target: ComponentInfo{com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.contact.sync.ContactsSyncAdapterService}
```

Answer (score 4):

This definitely solved it for me.

added these to my /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  // <-- added this 
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. It worked